# Why does the vertical distance between the minipage and the image change when the amount of text in the minipage changes?

Tags: graphics, minipage

Is there a way to fix this, so that the vertical distance doesn't depend on the amount of text in the minipage?

Here is an example (the vertical distance doesn't equal \smallskip):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\captionlistentry[figure]{Title}
\begin{figure}[!htb]

    \centering

    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fredgraph.pdf}

    \smallskip

    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth} 
        {\footnotesize\textbf{Figure 1. Title.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
        ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero 
        eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd 
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        \par}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\captionlistentry[figure]{Title}
\begin{figure}[!htb]

    \centering

    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fredgraph.pdf}

    \smallskip

    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth} 
        {\footnotesize\textbf{Figure 1. Title.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy \par}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use top alignment of the `minipage`s.

By default, the `minipage` is vertically centered and closely cropped to the text.  If it exceeds 1 line, it pushes upward against the image with the close cropping.  By using the `[t]` option, the top row of text will be aligned along the baseline the same as a 1-row caption would be.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\captionlistentry[figure]{Title}
\begin{figure}[!htb]

    \centering

    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fredgraph.pdf}

    \smallskip

    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth} 
        {\footnotesize\textbf{Figure 1. Title.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
        ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero 
        eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd 
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        \par}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\captionlistentry[figure]{Title}
\begin{figure}[!htb]

    \centering

    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{fredgraph.pdf}

    \smallskip

    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth} 
        {\footnotesize\textbf{Figure 1. Title.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy \par}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]